# Who was Madam in this episode of Batman: The Animated Series?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

Re-watching the episode "Baby Doll" of *Batman: The Animated Series* (technically they changed the name by that point to Adventures of Batman and Robin). I realized that Baby Doll’s henchmen were supposed to be the Skipper and Gilligan from Gilligan’s Island. Is Madam (the red headed bodyguard) supposed to be a reference to another sitcom character? Ginger from Gilligan’s Island doesn’t seem right; Skipper and Gilligan had clothes and physical bodies and haircuts that identified them as such, whereas Madam just has the red hair.

[image]

Comment: When I see "Madame", the first thing I think of is [Wayland Flowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_Flowers)' ventriloquist puppet. However, her hair was gray, as far as I can tell (she was basically always seen wearing some sort of fancy hat). It's been a few years since I last saw that episode, so I don't recall if there's anything in the henchwoman's mannerisms that would match up - it seems somewhat unlikely, given Baby Doll's temperament, but it might be more evidently in her dealings with the other henchmen.

Comment: Her name is Mariam. I don't think she is a reference to anyone but she has some resemblance to Catwoman's /Selina Kyle's assistant and secretary Maven. Mostly because she is a redhead with glasses.